# Cleansing off HTML tags using readability

Tags: python

I am using `readbility` to retrieve some HTML pages. I need to get body text from an HTML page without HTML tags. Can I do this with `readability`?

Comment: Do you want the whole page, or a specific part? Is it that the page has no HTML tags, or that you want the extract to have no HTML tags?

Comment: I want to extract the text so it doesn't have any html tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the source code of `readability`, I've found that while there does appear to be a way of cleaning the HTML using the library's `cleaners` module, the methods used to retrieve the content (which use `lxml`) store it as unicode text. This is a problem, because the method used by `cleaners` to remove the HTML tags returns an `AttriuteError` for unicode objects:

```
import requests
from readability import Document

response = requests.get('http://example.com')
doc = Document(response.text)
doc.summary()
# raw content of HTML page with tags
doc.get_clean_html()
# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_clean_html'
```

It appears, too, that this package hasn't seen active development for some time and therefore has many bugs.

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is another, better developed library which does everything that `readability` does and more. There is also [an excellent answer](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this same problem which uses BeautifulSoup instead. This is a long-term solution.

In the short-term, depending on how complicated the page is, you may be able to use `re` to remove all of the HTML tags and leave the text, as shown below using my website:

```
import re
import requests
from readability import Document

response = requests.get('http://ryanmcginnis.co/')
doc = Document(response.text)
cleanme = doc.summary()
print(re.sub('<.*?>', '', cleanme))
```

This program returns the pure text from my text-only website.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I wanted to bring a bit of nuaces here. Regarding the original problem: BeautifulSoup4 can infact get you the text of readbility with get_text() after you built your soup object on it. But bs4 and readbility are not the same tool. Bs4 is an html/xml parser that help you work with the parse tree and readbility extract the main content of a web page. So now, you can just use both (readability got an active fork here: https://github.com/buriy/python-readability), readability -> bs4 -> get_text()

Comment: *There is also an excellent answer for this same* - the provided link directs to BeautifulSoup documentation, not a StackOverflow answer, if that's what you mean. Also, as commented above, BeautifulSoup is not a *library which does everything that readability does*, they do different things.